# Firestore doc ID to query update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using react and firestore.

I have the following code to query users data

```
componentWillMount() {
db.collection("user")
  .get()
  .then(collection => {
    this.setState({
      userlist: collection.docs.map(doc => doc.data()),
      loading: false
    });
  });
}
```

I have a component where I can manage the selected user.

And on click on the save button, I need of course to update the selected user.

But inside `data()`, there is no ids of documents. I know I can get the id with doc.id, but I need it inside `data()`, to after query the update with the good doc id.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
componentWillMount() {
db.collection("user")
  .get()
  .then(collection => {
    this.setState({
      userlist: collection.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})),
      loading: false
    });
  });
}
```

This way you assign id to the data object before return it from the `map` callback.